# How to use logging in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have a Cross Platform Logging in Xamarin application in *MVVMLight* framework. In this framework all classes are `PCL`(Portable Class Lib). And want to use Logging in Xamarin with *MVVMLight* framework.

**Note:** I have already used `NLog` for logging, and although it's working for `PCL`(Normal Console App) it doesn't work for `PCL` in *MVVMLight*. I have looked at [Nlog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog) and so far they are not supported in the `PCL` projects for various reasons (most around File IO)
Please let me know, how have you implemented logging in `PCL`'s (design patterns, etc...)?